# XDocument declaration fails

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've been coding a chat program that uses `System.Net`. I also have a config XML file I put in `%appdata%\.ilan`, but when I want to declare a new `XDocument` type variable, Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 doesn't recognize it as a variable, and when I finish the entire variable it says `get or set accessor expected`. I have made a different program in the same Studio that uses XDocument, and it works there!
I have `System.Xml;` and `System.Xml.Linq;` at the top, so I have no idea what's wrong with my code:

```
public void DefaultXML
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XComment(" - IlanChat Settings File - "),
    new XElement("settings",
        new XElement("nick", "User")));
}
```

I have compared it to my previous program and the syntax is the same.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to put parentheses after the method name:

```
public void DefaultXML()   // <--
```

Without the parentheses, the IDE thinks you're declaring a *property* instead of a method. That's why it thinks you're missing a get or set accessor.

Comment: Oh dear, I wonder why my IDE hasn't told me.. And @gunr my code is horrible but it works! I'm just a beginner, started learning a month ago :)